# Prcomp: info on scale argument

Tags: r, prcomp

I was using `prcomp()` on R for the first time and I was wondering on the description about the `scale` argument, this part in particular:

> The default is FALSE for consistency with S, but in general scaling is advisable.

I couldn't find in the rest of documentation any reference to S. What does it stand for?

Comment: It's probably referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_(programming_language) which is R "father"

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that coming; do you know the logic on why is it set that way or some other references that I can check?

Comment: The default is FALSE for consistency, as the doc says. Probably S had the same default value. That's not something to worry about, you should scale usually anyway.

Comment: That's for sure, I was just curious about it.